# Doctest python - Ignore order of lists

Tags: python, doctest

Is there a doctest directive to ignore the order of the elements while matching the expected and the returned lists.

This fails currently:

```
Expected:
  ['foo', 'bar']
Got:
  ['bar', 'foo']
```

Comment: Maybe you want to use a `set` instead of a `list`?

Comment: A `list` is an ordered data structure, so ignoring it goes against the point of using such a data structure to begin with. What is the test exactly?

Answer (score 3):

Doctest always matches string output. If you want to ignore the order of list elements one recommended solution is to use `sorted`.

The the last example from this excerpt from the [doctest docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html):

> doctest is serious about requiring exact matches in expected output.
> If even a single character doesn’t match, the test fails. This will
> probably surprise you a few times, as you learn exactly what Python
> does and doesn’t guarantee about output. For example, when printing a
> set, Python doesn’t guarantee that the element is printed in any
> particular order, so a test like
>
> ```
> >>>
> >>> foo()
> {"Hermione", "Harry"}
> ```
>
> is vulnerable! One workaround is to do
>
> ```
> >>>
> >>> foo() == {"Hermione", "Harry"}
> True
> ```
>
> instead. Another is to do
>
> ```
> >>>
> >>> d = sorted(foo())
> >>> d
> ```
>
> ['Harry', 'Hermione']

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved.

Turns out I was printing the list and so doctest was trying to match strings instead of lists.

FTR, doctest does match lists ignoring the order of elements.

Comment: Hi @priyansh-agrawal , this seems to be an incorrect "resolve". Doctest matches string output. See my answer with examples from the doctest docs.